# Retry Async/Await 3 times then display alert, alert not showing

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to run my function 3 times if `refreshAppData()` returns false or causes an error. However, I cannot get the function to fire again after the initial call.

How can I retry my async / await and show an error after three attempts?

```
async function tryRefreshAppData(retries) {
    const refreshOk = await refreshAppData();

    if (!refreshOk && retries > 0) {
        return tryRefreshAppData(retries - 1);
    }
    alert("refreshAppData was unsuccessful")
    throw new Error("Failed to load the data correctly");
}

const MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES = 3;
const RETRIES = MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES - 1;

await tryRefreshAppData(RETRIES);
```

Comment: What you have done looks like it should work, can you knock up a snippet showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done seems to already work but you should handle the case where refreshAppData() throw an error. I put an example below :

```js
async function refreshAppData(retries) {
  if (retries === 1) {
    return Promise.resolve("ok");
  }
  return Promise.reject("tizzi");
}

async function tryRefreshAppData(retries) {
  try {
    const refreshOk = await refreshAppData(retries);

    if (!refreshOk && retries > 0) {
      return tryRefreshAppData(retries - 1);
    }
    console.log("SUCCESS", refreshOk);
    return refreshOk;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("ERROR");
    if (retries > 0) {
      return tryRefreshAppData(retries - 1);
    }
    throw new Error("Failed to load the data correctly");
  }
}

const MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES = 3;
const RETRIES = MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES;

tryRefreshAppData(RETRIES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution (written in `TS` tho).
you can replace `resolve()` with `reject()` in order to test it of course:

```
const MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES = 3;
const RETRIES = MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES - 1;

const tryRefreshAppData: (iteration: number) => Promise<void> = (iteration) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(iteration);
    resolve();
  }, 1000);
});

async function doAsyncCall()  {
  const iterations = Array.from({length: MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES}, (v,i) => i);
  let failedAttempts = 0;

  for(const iteration in iterations) {
    try {
      await tryRefreshAppData(parseInt(iteration));

      break;
    } catch {
        failedAttempts +=1;
    }
  }

  if(failedAttempts === MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES) {
      alert("refreshAppData was unsuccessful");
  }
}

doAsyncCall();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.catch()` method on `refreshAppData` and return `false`:

```js
function refreshAppData(retries) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( function() {
      reject("Error!");
    }, 750);
  })
}

async function tryRefreshAppData(retries) {
    console.log('retries', retries);
    const refreshOk = await refreshAppData().catch(err => false);
    if (!refreshOk && retries > 0) {
        console.log('retry');
        return tryRefreshAppData(retries - 1);
    }
    alert("refreshAppData was unsuccessful");
    throw new Error("Failed to load the data correctly");
}

const MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES = 3;
const RETRIES = MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES - 1;

(async function() { await tryRefreshAppData(RETRIES); })()
```

You could also use `try...catch` and use the `catch` block to retry/show an error:

```js
function refreshAppData(retries) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( function() {
      reject("Error!");
    }, 750);
  })
}

async function tryRefreshAppData(retries) {
    console.log('retries', retries);
    try {
      const refreshOk = await refreshAppData(retries);
    } catch(err) {
      if (retries > 0) {
        console.log('retry');
        return tryRefreshAppData(retries - 1);
      }
      alert("refreshAppData was unsuccessful")
      throw new Error("Failed to load the data correctly");
    }
}

const MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES = 3;
const RETRIES = MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES - 1;

(async function() { await tryRefreshAppData(RETRIES); })()
```